# what is the return type of typeof?

Tags: c, gcc, typeof

I want to provide the type of an element as parameter to an initialization of an array of pointers to element of an unknown types

something like

```
void* init(type t)
  void* array = malloc(sizeof_type(t)*10));
  return array;
}
```

and later call for example

```
   init(typeof(int))
```

But I was not able to figure what is the return type of typeof.

I guess the sizeof_type think can be achieved using

```
   malloc((type) 0);
```

Thanks in advance

PS: this if for a vector implementatin if someone can point me to some flexiblecode i would be very thankful as well

Comment: this should be retagged, this doesn't look like C at all

Comment: perhaps this will help: http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/gcc/typeof.html Also maybe this: http://www.accu-usa.org/Listings/2000-05-Listing01.html

Comment: I would be very wary of using typeof() unless I was sure I wanted my program to only work on GNU.

Answer (score 3):

I don't usually use gnu (I think it is only in gnu C), but I don't think it's an expression in the normal sense that you can assign its value to a variable and later use it. I think it can only be used in very specific contexts as a type.

[From the docs:](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)

> The syntax of using of this keyword
>   looks like sizeof, but the construct
>   acts semantically like a type name
>   defined with typedef.
>
> A typeof-construct can be used
>   anywhere a typedef name could be used.
>   For example, you can use it in a
>   declaration, in a cast, or inside of
>   sizeof or typeof.

Comment: good to learn I can do `typeof(typeof(typof(typeof(c))))` and that it does the same as `typeof(c)` ;-)

Comment: Thanks so it is probably not possible. That basically means I have to provide a protoype element instead of the type

Answer (score 3):

What you want is not possible.

typeof() does not really return a type, since it is a keyword which is evaluated at *compile-time*. It is replaced by the name for the type of its parameter.

<s>Maybe you can</s> *You can not* use the stringification operator of the preprocessor to make it a string, like this ##typeof(a), but then it would still be impossible to malloc/cast something when you have the type in a string.

Comment: 1. Stringification won't work, because typeof() cannot be evaluated at preprocessing stage. You will get just the string "typeof(a)" for your troubles.

Comment: 2. "##" is actually token glueing, not stringification.

Comment: +1. and remove the last paragraph, makes no sense. from what you say  typeof() is evaluated at compile time, then it is too late for preprocessor tricks.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just use sizeof?
something like:

```
int c;
void *p = calloc( 10,sizeof(c) );
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
#define INIT(t) (malloc(sizeof(t) * 10))
```

may be used like this:

```
int* a = INIT(int);
```

or possibly like this:

```
void* b = INIT(typeof(c));
```

or even this:

```
void* b = INIT(c);
```

since `sizeof(c) == sizeof(typeof(c))`.

Comment: or even `void * b = INIT(c)` as `sizeof` accept a variable (works like if there was an implicit `typeof`)

Answer (score 0):

I know your question wasn't tagged as such, but if you happen to be able to use C++, you may want to look into using template classes. Libraries like STL use templates to provide (type) universal containers and algorithms.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use a macro for this purpose:

```
#define INIT(t) ((t*) init_1(sizeof(t)))

void *init_1(size_t sz) {
  void *array = malloc(sz * 10);
  return array;
}
```

Then you use like:

```
int *array = INIT(int);
```

Comment: There is no reason to cast the result. Simply use the `void *` for what it was intended for. (See casting the return value of malloc considered harmful.)

Comment: @R.. You are wrong in this case. Take a better look, I'm **not** casting the return value of malloc(), so your concerns do not apply here. I'm casting the return value of init_1() so that the expression has the appropriate type. This is important, so that the compiler flags errors like assigning `INIT(int)` to a `char*`, for example. The point of not using a cast in the malloc() return is to prevent the compiler from using an implicit malloc() declaration which returns int and is casted to a pointer type, which causes UB.

Comment: Note that, since I'm actually not casting the return of malloc(), if the user forgets to include <stdlib.h>, the compiler will issue a warning for converting an int to pointer in the line with malloc(). The type casting in the #define line is harmless, since the definition of init_1() is there, the compiler knows that the function returns a pointer, and the cast does a safe pointer to pointer conversion and causes the expression to have the correct type.